# Wrong product produced in pairwise error estimation in R

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, pairwise

I want to produce a pairwise error from a melted matrix which seems like this:

```
pw.data = data.frame(true_tree = rep(c("maple","oak","pine"),3), 
                 guess_tree = c(rep("maple",3),rep("oak",3),rep("pine",3)),
                 value = c(12,0,1,1,15,0,2,1,14))


true_tree guess_tree value
  maple      maple    12
    oak      maple     0
   pine      maple     1
  maple        oak     1
    oak        oak    15
   pine        oak     0
  maple       pine     2
    oak       pine     1
   pine       pine    14
```

So I want to estimate the pairwise error between true species of the trees and guessed ones. For this estimation, formula should be "pairwise wrong assignments/ All the number of estimations for the chosen two species.

To give a better explanation: Wrong guess for maple and oak (maple-oak and oak-maple comparisons) = 1 + 0 / all number of guesses = 12 + 1 + 2 (all counts for true_tree == "maple) + 0 + 15 + 1 (all counts for true_tree == "oak). So the estimation product is 1/31.

When I checked it for one specific case, let's say  again for maple and oak, I can estimate it manually like:

```
sum(pw.data[((pw.data[,1] == "maple" & pw.data[,2] == "oak") | 
      (pw.data[,1] == "oak" & pw.data[,2] == "maple")) &
      (pw.data[,1] != pw.data[,2]),3]) / 
 (sum(pw.data[pw.data[,1] == "maple",3]) + sum(pw.data[pw.data[,1] == "oak",3]))
```

However, I want to make this estimations for bigger data and therefore, I want  to create a for loop/function to make the estimation itself and store the results in a data frame such as:

```
Pw_tree   value
Maple-oak 0.0123
....
```

I have tried to use that logic in a for loop such below but it doesn't work at all.

```
for (i in pw.data[,1]) { 
for (j in pw.data[,2]) {
x = sum( pw.data[((pw.data[,1] == i & pw.data[,2] == j ) | 
                (pw.data[,1] == j & pw.data[,2] == i)) &
               (pw.data[,1] != pw.data[,2]),3])  
y = (sum(pw.data[pw.data[,1] == i,3]) + sum(pw.data[pw.data[,1] == j,3]))
   PWerr_data = data.frame( pw_tree = paste(i,j, sep = "-"), value = x/y)
 }

}
```

That would be great, If I could see what I did wrong.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually tackle these types of problems by building the function I want to apply (which you have almost done), and then building the data structure it would be most convenient to apply it to, and then I can use one of the `apply` family of functions to iterate across my data-structure for the results. This lets me avoid `for` loop structures, which is good because I'm the kind of programmer who will invariably screw up an index in a double for loop.

In your case, we can wrap your ratio of sums into a function that takes a data.frame and two tree names as arguments. Then we just need to create the set of pairs that we want to work with. A handy function is `combn()` which lets you take all combinations of size `m` from the elements of `x`: this will give us our desired set of non-redundant pairs.

Commented example code below:

```r
# Load your data
pw.data = data.frame(true_tree = rep(c("maple","oak","pine"),3), 
                     guess_tree = c(rep("maple",3),rep("oak",3),rep("pine",3)),
                     value = c(12,0,1,1,15,0,2,1,14))
pw.data
#>   true_tree guess_tree value
#> 1     maple      maple    12
#> 2       oak      maple     0
#> 3      pine      maple     1
#> 4     maple        oak     1
#> 5       oak        oak    15
#> 6      pine        oak     0
#> 7     maple       pine     2
#> 8       oak       pine     1
#> 9      pine       pine    14

# build the function we will repeatedly apply
getErr <- function(t1, t2, data=pw.data) {
  # compute the rate as you wrote it
  rate <- sum(data[((pw.data[,1] == t1 & data[,2] == t2) | 
               (data[,1] == t2 & data[,2] == t1)) &
              (data[,1] != data[,2]),3]) / 
  (sum(data[data[,1] == t1,3]) + sum(data[data[,1] == t2,3]))

  # output the items involved as a named list (useful for later)
  list(Pw_tree = paste(t1, t2, sep='-'), error_rate = rate)
  }

# test it
getErr("maple", "oak")
#> $Pw_tree
#> [1] "maple-oak"
#> 
#> $error_rate
#> [1] 0.03225806
# Good this matches the output you supplied

# build the data structure we will run the function across
all.trees <- unique(c(as.character(pw.data$true_tree), as.character(pw.data$guess_tree)))
all.name.combos <- combn(all.trees, 2)

# we will use the do.call(rbind, ls) trick, where we generate a list
# with the apply function and coerce it to a matrix
error_rates_df <- do.call(rbind, apply(all.name.combos, 2, function(row){getErr(row[1], row[2])}))
error_rates_df
#>      Pw_tree      error_rate
#> [1,] "maple-oak"  0.03225806
#> [2,] "maple-pine" 0.1       
#> [3,] "oak-pine"   0.03225806
```

<sup>Created on 2018-10-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot. it is working great for big datasets and thanks a lot for simplifying it in a better way!